# install tomcat 8.0.24 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I follow the steps largely from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04

Let me iterate the steps I took:

1. i logged in as ubuntu user
2. `sudo apt-get install tomcat8`
3. `sudo groupadd tomcat`
4. `sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat`
5. `cd ~`
6. `wget http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.24/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.24.tar.gz`
7. `sudo mkdir /opt/tomcat`
8. `sudo tar xvf apache-tomcat-8*tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1`
9. `cd /opt/tomcat`
10. `sudo chgrp -R tomcat conf`
11. `sudo chmod g+rwx conf`
12. `sudo chmod g+r conf/*`
13. `sudo chown -R tomcat work/ temp/ logs/`
14. `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and selected `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`
15. `sudo nano /etc/init/tomcat.conf`

and typed

```
description "Tomcat Server"

  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [!2345]
  respawn
  respawn limit 10 5

  setuid tomcat
  setgid tomcat

  env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
  env CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat

  # Modify these options as needed
  env JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
  env CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

  exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run

  # cleanup temp directory after stop
  post-stop script
    rm -rf $CATALINA_HOME/temp/*
  end script
```

16. `sudo initctl reload-configuration`
17. `sudo initctl start tomcat`

which leads to

`tomcat start/running, process 14674`

But when I go to http://[ip-address]:8080 nothing happens.

Please advise.

**UPDATE**

One comment below asked me to look at server.xml inside tomcat root folder bin.

I have reproduced the following files:

[image]

Which proves that there is no such file inside /opt/tomcat/bin

I have also appended *some* statements from server.xml below which is inside `/opt/tomcat/conf`

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Comment: check the port no is `server.xml`

Comment: where is server.xml? and I found one server.xml inside /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml. There are 3 different port numbers stated: 8005, 8080, 8009. so which one is meant for which?

Comment: no such file. See above.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: In the end, I didn't solve my ultimate issue with tomcat

Comment: @KimStacks What does `sudo /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh` output?

Comment: Can you share your logs ? You can find it under ```/var/log/tomcat8```

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat
```

This worked for me after useing the very same manual.

Answer (score 1):

If you want clean Ubuntu style package instead, the following should do it...

```
mkdir $HOME/tomcat8 && cd $HOME/tomcat8
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/e/ecj/libecj-java_3.10.1-2_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tomcat8/libservlet3.1-java_8.0.28-1_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tomcat8/libtomcat8-java_8.0.28-1_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tomcat8/tomcat8-common_8.0.28-1_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tomcat8/tomcat8_8.0.28-1_all.deb
dpkg -i *.deb
```

However, you're not on PPA. This isn't managed by apt anymore. You'll need to upgrade it manually whenever an update is made to the packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I installed **Oracle JDK 7**, HOWEVER, I still used `JAVA_HOME` in `tomcat.conf` that was pointing to **Open JDK**:

```
env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

Make sure you are using the right version of Java. For me, I set it in `tomcat.conf` as follows:

```
env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
```

Then, do `ps -ef | grep tomcat` after re-starting tomcat and you should get something like this if tomcat is running:

```
tomcat    1580     1  9 14:47 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Dja
ger=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=2
ParallelGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcat
t -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
ubuntu    1607  1423  0 14:48 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

Also, my `environment` file has the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre"
export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:  http://serverip:8080 
I used http://localhost:8080

That replacement worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution for installing any version of apache tomcat on Ubuntu.

**Simplest Way of Installing any version Apache Tomcat Installation Steps on Ubuntu.**

1. **Download** any version of tomcat you wish to install  from apache tomcat official website.(.tar/.zip)
2. **Extract** the tomcat tar/zip file to any folder/directory in your linux pc.
3. Copy the extracted folder to /opt directory
   directory looks like **/opt/tomcat** using cp command.

   for e.g. **sudo cp /Documents/apache-tomcat-8-0-24        /opt**

   This will copy my  apache-tomcat-8-0-24 folder in Documents folder to  /opt directory.
4. come back to /opt directory /opt
   **cd /opt**
5. you are at /opt run following command
   **sudo chown -R username:username**

   **for e.g. sudo chown -R akashgudadhe apache-tomcat-8-0-24**
6. you are at /opt
   **ls -la** 
   verify apache present or not
7. **move to apache-tomcat-8-0-24 folder and bin directory inside it**

   **/opt/apacheTomcatName/bin**
8. you are now at /opt/apacheTomcatName/bin

   run startup.sh file using following command you will see the message tomcat started.

   **for e.g. /opt/apacheTomcatName/bin/./startup.sh**
9. This is optional step
   tail -f logs/catalina.out
10. Open any web browser and type
    **localhost:8080 or type 127.0.0.1:8080**
    your tomcat installed successfully if not then mail me @ gooddaysky1@gmail.com

It will become great pleasure for me  if you send me your feedback about my answer  @ gooddaysky1@gmail.com ...!!!

Answer (score -1):

Open `Server.xml` and find `<Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"` so that is your port number .

Comment: I am not asking about my port number. Please see above. I have it correctly as 8080

Answer (score -1):

You have to write:
cd /opt/tomcat/bin

and after:

sudo bash startup.sh

and all well!!!
http://serverip:8080

NOTE: If you put the port 9090, then PLACED IN YOUR BROWSER http://serverip:9090

Comment: Where do you see sudo bash startup.sh?